# Looking for fancy industrial applications of clustering

Tags: clustering, k-means

I'm going to supervise a high school student project. The goal is to have them discover data mining by "reinventing" the K-means algorithm and, eventually, going farther than the basic K-means.

The project is optional, so I first have to convince them to join me. I thought that for that purpose it would be nice to convince them of the utility of clustering in our lives. Therefore I need some examples of fancy (and easy-to-understand) industrial applications of clustering.

For the moment all I could find was:

1. in a bunch of cancerous cells find new types of cancer that may have
   escaped observation
2. market segmentation: divide a population of customers into classes and address them with specific marketing strategies
3. obtaining a palette of colors for indexed bitmap formats.

Although important, these three applications are not glamorous enough for high-school students (the first is creepy except for those who want to study medicine, the second of little interest to them and the third requires so much technical explanations that they will stop listening after 20 seconds).

Could you please help me by providing some really fancy applications of clustering (unsupervised classification)?

Comment: High school student interest? Sex. Maybe you could define sex-related features and cluster people on them. I think it would even interest me....

Comment: My daughter will be in the group and I don't feel at ease bringing up such kinds of examples in front of her...

Comment: You know, I wrote as a kind of silly comment but the more I think about the more I like it. It should be done in a good and educational way though, getting help from somebody who is definitively not an engineer... I even listened to [this postcast from partially derivative](http://www.partiallyderivative.com/news/2015/8/5/episode-30-up-all-night-for-love-and-data), one of the guests states "one of the many reasons sex is puzzling is that we lack reliable data". But anyway if your daughter is in I understand!

Answer (score 2):

How about music and movie recommendations? I would bet donuts to dollars high school students care about this.

Comment: IMHO K-means would cluster movies (or music songs) into (unlabeled) groups rather than recommend them. What kind of application do you have in mind?

Comment: Once you have the works clustered, you could ask a user to list some favorites ones and use their clusters for additional recommendations.

Comment: I see. But what makes the clustering of music songs by K-means a better clustering that the one provided, for example, by record companies? Is there a way to personalize the clustering for each user?

Comment: I am not aware that record companies do any such clustering. The recommendation will be "personalized" unless each user submits an identical list.